# Alter images in kinetic

Tags: kineticjs

I have the following object:

```
thegirls.onload = function() { 
       thegirls = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 50,
          y: 30,
          image: thegirls,
          width: 106,
          height: 118
        });
         layer2.add(thegirls);


        layer2.draw();
        }
    thegirls.src = "01.png";
```

I want to make a function to change an image, but I can't change the picture

code:

```
function changegirls (){

thegirls.src = "02.png";
  layer2.draw();

}
```

thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .setImage to change a Kinetic.Image's image

```
var kGirls;

thegirls.onload = function() { 
       kGirls = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 50,
          y: 30,
          image: thegirls,
          width: 106,
          height: 118
        });
        layer2.add(kGirls);
        layer2.draw();
}
thegirls.src = "01.png";


function changegirls (){

    var img02=new Image();
    img02.onload=function(){
        kGirls.setImage(img02);
        layer2.draw();
    }
    img02.src = "02.png";

}
```